# How to install nodejs 0.12.7

Tags: node.js

I've trying to install the latest version of nodejs

```
sudo apt-get nodejs
```

installs the version 0.12.25
When I downloaded the tar.gz from https://nodejs.org/ and installed
my node version upgraded to 0.12.7 but not nodejs version.
And when I tried like this

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.12.7
```

E: Version '0.12.7' for 'nodejs' was not found

This error popped up. What can I do such that on entering

```
nodejs -v
```

I can get 0.12.7

Answer (score 4):

Since there are a lot of Node.js versions, and there is also [iojs](https://iojs.org), I suggest you to use a straightforward Node.js version manager, like the very good [n](https://github.com/tj/n).

So, first install **n**, then install Node.js 0.12.7 with:

```
$ n 0.12.7
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install node.js from source by default it will install with node as name of the executable

```
node -v
```

Will show 0.12.7

If you need node.js for development purposes on your machine you can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), it allows to install different versions of node.js and io.js, and easily switch between them

Answer (score 0):

Remove `node` with command `sudo apt-get remove node`, then remove `nodejs` using `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`. After that try to install `nodejs` again with version you need `sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.12.7`.